# ggplot2 "borders" of filled points

Tags: r, ggplot2

So first: I'm wholly new to programming and this is my second(?) week of R, so apologies in advance.

I'm using pch=21 and using a fill color to show a factor, but I'd like to control the border size of the points.

Is there any way to increase the border size of pch 21? Or is there another way of adding borders to points that will allow me to control border size?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=model,y=cty))+
geom_point(color="black",size=3,pch=21,aes(fill=manufacturer))
```

The reason this is a problem is because I'd like to use white filled points on a white background (it's just a common style in my field), but they're too hard to see unless I make the black border more distinct.

Comment: Yep, there's a `stroke` aesthetic, e.g. `ggplot(mpg, aes(model, cty, fill = manufacturer)) +
    geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, stroke = 1)`

Comment: Annnd... Solved. Thank you!

Comment: And `stroke` is described using shape 21 as an example in the help document: `?geom_point`.

Comment: I've been using the webpage manual. When I saw your comment, I went to it, and I had that exact example visible at the bottom of the screen... I don't know how I missed that... Sorry.